# Problems with Gaussian Quadrature in R

Tags: r, math, statistics

I'm using the the gaussquad package to evaluate some integrals numerically.

I thought the ghermite.h.quadrature command worked by evaluating a function *f*(x) at points *x1*, ..., *xn* and then constructing the sum *w1*f*(x1) + ... + *wn*f*(xn), where *x1*, ..., *xn* and *w1*, ..., *wn* are nodes and weights supplied by the user.

Thus I thought the commands

```
ghermite.h.quadrature(f,rule)
sum(sapply(rule$x,f)*rule$w)
```

would yield the same output for any function *f*, where ''rule'' is a dataframe which stores the nodes in a column labelled ''x'' and the weights in a column labelled "w". For many functions the output is indeed the same, but for some functions I get very different results. Can someone please help me understand this discrepancy?

Thanks!

Code:

```
n.quad = 50 
rule = hermite.h.quadrature.rules(n.quad)[[n.quad]]

f <- function(z){ 

 f1 <- function(x,y) pnorm(x+y)

 f2 <- function(y) ghermite.h.quadrature(f1,rule,y = y)

 g <- function(x,y) x/(1+y) / f2(y)*pnorm(x+y)

 h <- function(y) ghermite.h.quadrature(g,rule,y=y)

 h(z)

}

ghermite.h.quadrature(f,rule)
sum(sapply(rule$x,f)*rule$w)
```

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Ok I added it

Comment: Could confirm values are really different, 0.34 vs 0.203

Comment: Normalization problem? ratio of results is close to \sqrt(\pi)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that problem got me interested.

I've looked into `gaussquad` sources, and clearly author is not running `sapply` internally, because all integrands/function shall return vector on vector argument.

It is clearly stated in documentation:

`functn` an **R** function which should take a numeric argument x and possibly some parameters.
The function returns a numerical vector value for the given argument `x`

In case where you're using some internal functions, they're written that way, so everything works.

You have to rewrite your function to work with vector argument and return back a vector

UPDATE

Vectorize() works for me to rectify the problem, as well as simple wrapper with sapply

```
vf <- function(z) {
    sapply(z, f)
}
```

After either of those changes, results are identical: `0.2029512`

Comment: Can I use Vectorize() to do this?